# math_errhandling undeclared in C (Windows 10 OS)

Tags: c, errno

I am trying to understand the inner workings of errno, and tried the following example file from cppreference, but got errors during compiling:

```
$ gcc errno_ex.c 
errno_ex.c: In function 'main':
errno_ex.c:33:10: error: 'math_errhandling' undeclared (first use in this function)
     puts(math_errhandling & MATH_ERRNO ? "set" : "not set");
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
errno_ex.c:33:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
errno_ex.c:33:29: error: 'MATH_ERRNO' undeclared (first use in this function)
     puts(math_errhandling & MATH_ERRNO ? "set" : "not set");
                             ^~~~~~~~~~
```

The (untouched) example code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>

void show_errno(void)
{
    const char *err_info = "unknown error";
    switch (errno) {
    case EDOM:
        err_info = "domain error";
        break;
    case EILSEQ:
        err_info = "illegal sequence";
        break;
    case ERANGE:
        err_info = "pole or range error";
        break;
    case 0:
        err_info = "no error";
    }
    fputs(err_info, stdout);
    puts(" occurred");
}

int main(void)
{
    fputs("MATH_ERRNO is ", stdout);
    puts(math_errhandling & MATH_ERRNO ? "set" : "not set");
 
    errno = 0;
    1.0/0.0;
    show_errno();
 
    errno = 0;
    acos(+1.1);
    show_errno();
 
    errno = 0;
    log(0.0);
    show_errno();
 
    errno = 0;
    sin(0.0);
    show_errno();
}
```

I am not sure what is happening. These errors happen when I compile in VS code in Windows ( C complier set to `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30037/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe` by default, and using `C17` standard).

When I try to duplicate this on my Macbook VS code, it compiled without error. So I am not sure where is the problem: is my compiler too old to recognize these macros?

Edit:
I think the macro definition of `math_errhandling` is platform-specific, thus not quite portable across different OS platforms. `errno` macro still works in my Windows-based VS Code IDE, which I am happy with. It is just that the `math_errhandling` thing is a bit non-portable and mysterious.

Comment: I think you have to append `-lm` in the gcc command: `gcc errno_ex.c -lm`

Comment: @tttony I tried, but got the same errors nontheless.

Comment: I don't know what `math_errhandling` is, but I don't think it's standard.  I tested your code, and it compiled fine under both Linux and MacOS, but I'm not too surprised the magic `math_errhandling` thingie doesn't exist over in the Windows world.

Comment: @SteveSummit thank you for testing the code. From my humble understanding, `math_errhandling` should be a macro defined in `<errno.h>`, which means it is a short-hand substitution of a longer expression. So maybe I need to look under the hood, and check what is the actual definition of `math_errhandling` in `<errno.h>`?

Comment: you are trying to explore non standardized behavior, ie its an implementers choice. Windows does it different from Mac (and probably linux)

Comment: @pm100 I guess then it is a trivial thing and very unlikely to be used in actual work then? I am just learning and improving my C skills. I guess I will move on then.

Comment: @tttony Please do not mislead questioners! The error message comes clearly from the compiler, not from the linker. Therefore, the build has not even reached the phase where a missing function of a library is detected. It is as others say, `math_errhandling` and `MATH_ERRNO` are system-specific and not portable.